# Is there an efficient way to find all common substrings of 2 strings with mismatches allowed and designated length

Tags: python, bioinformatics, string-matching

I am looking for fast algorithm for finding all common substrings of 2 strings with max k mismatches and length L. 
For example, 
Input:
s1: ATCGGTAGCTAGCT
s2: ATCGATCGATCGATCG
k:1
L: 4

For now, my algorithm is

```
results = []
for every L-mer l1 in s1:
   for every L-mer l2 in s2:
       calculate hamming_distance(l1, l2)
       if hamming_distance(l1, l2) <= k:
           results.add(l1, l2) # or add index of l1 and l2
```

This algorithm takes too much time when dealing with long sequence. Are there more efficient algorithm. Thanks a lot

here is my code in python

```
def lcs_hamming_only_matches(s1: str, s2: str, k: int, length: int, matches_lst: List):
    """
    This lcs use hamming distance as string comparison method.
    """
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, len(s1) - length + 1):
        for j in range(0, len(s2) - length + 1):
            sub1 = s1[i: i + length]
            sub2 = s2[j: j + length]
            result = hamming_distance(sub1, sub2)
            if result <= k:
                matches_lst.append([i, j, result, sub1, sub2])
                count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: how do you compute your L-mer? and the hamming distance? It would be helpful if you provided a working piece of code. Have you considered using sets?

Comment: @Tranbi I just use list slicing. I use Hamming distacne function from Distance package. I have now add the code. Hopefully it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the number of matches (you only return `count` in your function), this will be much faster:

```
from collections import Counter
from distance import hamming
def lcs_hamming_only_matches(s1: str, s2: str, k: int, L: int):
    cnt = 0
    matches_lst = []
    lmer1 = Counter([s1[i:i+L] for i in range(len(s1)-L+1)])
    for j in range(len(s2)-L+1):
        cnt += sum([lmer1[x] for x in lmer1 if hamming(s2[j:j+L], x) <= k])
    return cnt
```

If you want the positions as well just build your own dictionary with lists of indexes instead of using `Counter`.

Answer (score 0):

So you should profile this first to confirm but my suspicion is that the "hamming_distance" function is probably eating up most of the computational time so my strategy would focus on avoiding calling that function as much as possible.

One possible strategy: For the first full iteration for "i", store the hamming_distance scores you calculated in an array because you can use them for the next iteration of "i" to determine when it's necessary to call hamming_distance.

For example, for the second iteration of "i" and second iteration of "j" you can use the 1st value in the array of hamming_values you've just stored to tell if the substring alignment would be necessary. If hamming distance was 1 or more greater than k, you don't have to call "hamming_distance" because you know it'll be a match. Conversely, if the hamming distance was 2 below or more than k, you also don't have to find the hamming distance because you know it won't be a match. You can extend this strategy by storing the calculated hamming distance values as they become necessary for each iteration of "i".